# Clearing airport security 35 minutes before flight

Tags: uk, airport-security, missed-flights

I am wondering whether the policy to deny access if security is cleared at least 35 minutes before the flight departure is common, or if it is specific to some airline companies or some airports only.

Also, does anyone know if it may apply only to intercontinental flights, or all?

I was denied access because of this, while I could have easily made it to the gate by the Gate closing time, 15 minutes later.

Comment: Can you add more details? Which airport? Which flight? Denied by whom?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It's possible, for example, for there to be additional screening requirements on certain routes, and the airline is within its rights to require you to to be available for such screening at a certain time before departure. I always run into this on BRU-IAD flights, for example, presumably heightened security because of the diplomatic and military traffic. It would help to know what airline and what route were involved.

Comment: Difficult to know how common it is but it's certainly not universal. I have cleared security less than 30 min before a flight. Heck, I have cleared security less than 5-10 min before a flight, which I went on to miss. Over the years, I have had problems for being too late or too early at the check-in/luggage drop off counter or at the gate itself but the luggage inspection staff never cared much.

Comment: Given the UK flag, I suspect this may be about LHR T5, where there's a 35 minutes "conformance" requirement for all flights.

Comment: Who denied you "access"? The security staff, gate staff, other?

Comment: 35 minutes in which country?  Going where? Intercontinental going where?

Comment: There are flights where you have to catch a connecting flight from the same airline where you need to collect your baggage, check these in, and go through security again. In some cases you only have half an hour to do this and you can be delayed.....

Comment: EU flights require luggage 30minute before going to gate. Anything later than that and you cannot board any more. If you not checking in you can show up at the gate 0 minutes before gate open and you can board. International flights generally want 60 minute back checkin but usually it is highly advisable to be there 120minutes for international flights. Not just to avoid getting stuck in traffic but if the flights get cancelled or delayed you know about there and then. It is never pleasant but it happens

Answer (score 5):

It's not particularly common, though it applies in some cases. The specifics depend on the airport and airline involved.

There are some deadlines that are extremely common and apply to most flights where the pilot doesn't greet you by name:

- Check-in/bag drop time: You must be checked in and have dropped off your checked luggage a certain time before the flight departs. This will vary depending on the airline's policy, and may depend on the airport, destination, and even frequent flyer status. It is often non-negotiable.
- Last-call boarding time. You must be at the gate ready to board a certain number of minutes before the flight's scheduled departure. This will also vary depending on the airline's policy, but also as a practical matter, on how quickly the boarding process is going. If the flight is still boarding and you join a long boarding line after the specified time, it's unlikely anybody will be there to stop you (this may not apply to airports that still have security at the gate). And the airline may choose, entirely at its discretion, to wait for connecting passengers so as to avoid the expense of accommodating them if they misconnect. If the flight is already boarded and the aircraft door is closed, you're likely out of luck.

Beyond that, the most common situation is that passengers are responsible for getting themselves through security and to the gate before the last-call time and can do so whenever they wish.

A significant exception, as gsnedders notes in comments, is London Heathrow. At T5, ["You must enter airport security at least 35 minutes before your flight departs."](http://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/airport-information/london-heathrow-airport/heathrow-t5#) The policy (with different time limits) has been applied to [all terminals at Heathrow](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1501329-conformance-now-all-lhr-terminals-all-airlines.html). This is a process they call "conformance" (or sometimes "Ready to Fly"), where boarding passes are scanned at security and the airline can determine roughly where passengers should be in their journey to the gate (check-in, security, lounge, etc...). Easyjet also has [a 30 minute policy](http://thepointsguy.com/2016/06/easyjet-charges-passengers-for-arriving-30-minutes-before-flights/) at Gatwick. The intent is to [avoid delays](https://www.businesstraveller.com/news/2013/07/29/heathrow-tracking-passengers-to-cut-delays/) by allowing baggage for no-show passengers to be removed, but the rules are enforced even for those passengers who do not have checked luggage.

Such policies aren't, in my experience, all that common outside of the UK, but it's a good idea to check the fine print on the airline's website if you think you'll be cutting it close.